# Diff output from two programs without temporary files

Tags: bash, file, diff

Say I have too programs `a` and `b` that I can run with `./a` and `./b`.

Is it possible to diff their outputs without first writing to temporary files?

Comment: Related: [How can I compare the output of two unix commands to find the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115545/how-can-i-compare-the-output-of-two-unix-commands-to-find-the-difference), [How do I diff the output of two commands?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229447/how-do-i-diff-the-output-of-two-commands)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Use `<(command)` to pass one command's output to another program as if it were a file name. Bash pipes the program's output to a pipe and passes a file name like `/dev/fd/63` to the outer command.

```
diff <(./a) <(./b)
```

Similarly you can use `>(command)` if you want to pipe something *into* a command.

This is called "Process Substitution" in Bash's man page.

Comment: One drawback to be aware of is that if ./a or ./b fails, the caller will not find that out.

Comment: The OP did tag the question bash, but for the record, this doesn't work in any other shell. It's a bash extension to the Posix utility standard.

Comment: I tried this solution with a Java program and got this error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('`. I tried again without parenthesis and got `-bash: java: No such file or directory`. Does it not work if the command has parameters?

Comment: @DigitalRoss - The solution can be extended to other shells using an alias.  In tcsh, the following ugliness works:  `alias diffcmd bash -c \'diff \<\(sh -c \!:1\) \<\( sh -c \!:2 \)\'`.  (Then for, example:  diffcmd "ls" "ls -a").

Comment: For anyone wandering in off Google, this also works under zsh. (Also, if you need to feed input into something which calls `fseek`, zsh offers `=(./a)` which can be used identically to `<(./a)` but uses a temporary file under the hood, which zsh will delete for you.)

Answer (score 28):

Adding to both the answers, if you want to see a side by side comparison, use `vimdiff`:

```
vimdiff <(./a) <(./b)
```

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: `vimdiff` creates beautiful, smart and interactive difference comparison views. It seems to come with the `vim` package on most systems.

Comment: `vimdiff` also shows not only the line that differs but also the specific text fragment that differs.

Answer (score 21):

One option would be to use [named pipes (FIFOs)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo):

```
mkfifo a_fifo b_fifo
./a > a_fifo &
./b > b_fifo &
diff a_fifo b_fifo
```

... but [John Kugelman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800207) is much cleaner.

Comment: You'd better remove the named pipes after using them, with `rm a_fifo b_fifo`.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone curious, this is how you perform process substitution in using the [Fish shell](http://fishshell.com/):

**Bash:**

```
diff <(./a) <(./b)
```

**Fish:**

```
diff (./a | psub) (./b | psub)
```

Unfortunately the implementation in fish is currently [deficient](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1040); fish will either hang or use a temporary file on disk. You also cannot use psub for output from your command.

Comment: This does not currently work correctly in fish. If the output of the programs is greater than one BUFSIZ, the command will hang. (or fish will actually just use a temporary file on disk)

Answer (score 8):

Adding a little more to the already good answers (helped me!):

The command `docker` outputs its help to `STD_ERR` (i.e. file descriptor 2)

I wanted to see if `docker attach` and `docker attach --help` gave the same output

`$ docker attach`

`$ docker attach --help`

Having just typed those two commands, I did the following:

`$ diff <(!-2 2>&1) <(!! 2>&1)`

!! is the same as !-1 which means run the command 1 before this one - the last command

!-2 means run the command two before this one

2>&1 means send file_descriptor 2 output (STD_ERR) to the same place as file_descriptor 1 output (STD_OUT)

Hope this has been of some use.

Answer (score 1):

For zsh, using `=(command)` automatically creates a temporary file and replaces `=(command)` with the path of the file itself. With normal Process Substitution, `$(command)` is replaced with the *output* of the command.

This zsh feature is very useful and can be used like so to compare the output of two commands using a diff tool, for example Beyond Compare:

```
bcomp  =(ulimit -Sa | sort) =(ulimit -Ha | sort)
```

For Beyond Compare, note that you must use `bcomp` for the above (instead of `bcompare`) since `bcomp` launches the comparison and **waits** for it to complete.  If you use `bcompare`, that launches comparison and immediately exits due to which the temporary files created to store the output of the commands disappear.

Read more here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html

Also notice this:

> Note that the shell creates a temporary file, and deletes it when the command is finished.

and the following which is the difference between `$(...)` and `=(...)` :

> If you read zsh's man page, you may notice that <(...) is another form of process substitution which is similar to =(...). There is an important difference between the two. In the <(...) case, the shell creates a named pipe (FIFO) instead of a file. This is better, since it does not fill up the file system; but it does not work in all cases. In fact, if we had replaced =(...) with <(...) in the examples above, all of them would have stopped working except for fgrep -f <(...). You can not edit a pipe, or open it as a mail folder; fgrep, however, has no problem with reading a list of words from a pipe. You may wonder why diff <(foo) bar doesn't work, since foo | diff - bar works; this is because diff creates a temporary file if it notices that one of its arguments is -, and then copies its standard input to the temporary file.