# How can I compare the output of two unix commands to find the difference?

Tags: unix

I prefer not to create new files. I want to accomplish something similar to:

```
cmd1 > a
cmd2 > b
cat a b b | sort | uniq -u
```

but without using files a and b.

Comment: Related: [Diff output from two programs without temporary files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800202/diff-output-from-two-programs-without-temporary-files), [How do I diff the output of two commands?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229447/how-do-i-diff-the-output-of-two-commands)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unix utilities are generally file oriented, so nothing quite does what you want.

However, zsh can autocreate temporary files with the following syntax:

`diff =(cmd1) =(cmd2)`

It can also create temporary named pipes (or use the special files `/dev/fdn` to reference anonymous pipes) with

`diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`

However, many `diff`s call `lseek()` on their input, so won't work with named pipes.

(`diff` is in general a more useful command for comparing very similar output than your pipeline above.)

See the "process substitution" section of the "zshexpn" man page for more details.

Comment: The `<(cmd)` syntax is a fairly standard one that is also supported by more widely-used shells such as bash.  I have used this with diff in the past without noticing any problems.

Comment: And, of course, this does not only word with `diff`. I use it for `vimdiff` and other tools as well.